# stripping the .pdf from a filename but unintentionally also removing the letter 'p' from the end of the name

Tags: python

im stripping the '.pdf' off of all the file names in a folder to then be able to convert the document into a .txt and .md file. for some reason it also unintentionally removes the letter 'p' from all the file names that end with it and unable to process the code further. This is the code in question below: path has been defined in previous cell:

```
    def stripfiles(path):
        onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))] 
        onlypdf = filter(lambda f: f.endswith(('.pdf','.PDF')), onlyfiles)
        stripfiles = [s.strip(".pdf") for s in onlypdf]
        return stripfiles
    stripfiles = stripfiles(path)
```

to confirm issue, I removed 'p' manually from one of the files and the code ran as expected until the next missing 'p' file name.

so the error is that my code is removing the trailing 'p' for some reason and can't figure out why.

When run previously it didn't have this issue.

Comment: "When run previously it didn't have this issue." -- Please expand on this.